# How to clear everything in winforms Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

I add `TreeView` into `Panel` if I click a button, but It appends `TreeView`. How can I clear everything in Panel? I tried `Panel1.Controls.Clear()` and `Panel1.Controls.Remove(treeView1)`. But nothing happened.

Comment: Panel.Controls.Clear(); Panel.Refresh(); ?

Comment: myTreeViewBase.Nodes.Clear(); Panel.Controls.Clear(), post your code.

Comment: Harry myTreeViewBase.Nodes.Clear(); works, thank you.

Comment: I will post as answer please accept :) @TurhanOnurDöğücü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
myTreeViewBase.Nodes.Clear();
```

This method removes all tree nodes from the collection.

[TreeNodeCollection.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)